# Collate results between a set of values and a stored procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of values in one column like DeviceId1, DeviceId2, DeviceId3 etc.
My Sample input consists of one table with one column like below.

```
Device

DeviceId1
DeviceId2
```

Now for each value in this column I want to pass the DeviceId1 into a stored procedure which will return more values corresponding to each Input passed. And I want final result to be like this in a single table.

```
Device       DeviceParameter1FromSP   DeviceParameter2FromSP

DeviceId1    100                      200
DeviceId2    120                      222
```

What is best approach to get this result?
Note: Stored procedure can not be changed.
I have not tried anything yet as I am unable to think an approach.

Comment: Kindly post your sample input date. You can use pivot function for this approach. But make clear of your question

Comment: @JimMacaulay: I have posted the sample input data.

Comment: How about the values like 100,200,... . How you are generating them?

Comment: @JimMacaulay: Those are the values returned by the SP against each item in Device column.

Comment: @ckv Is that SP useful to your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare cursor and exec your sp for each row in a loop

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (
    @DeviceId                INT,
    @DeviceParameter1FromSP  INT,
    @DeviceParameter2FromSP  INT,
)

DECLARE @DeviceId                INT, 
        @DeviceParameter1FromSP  INT,
        @DeviceParameter2FromSP  INT,

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DeviceId
    FROM dbo.DeviceList

OPEN cur 
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DeviceId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.YOUR_SP_NAME @DeviceId, @DeviceParameter1FromSP OUTPUT, @DeviceParameter2FromSP OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO @result VALUES(@DeviceId, @DeviceParameter1FromSP, @DeviceParameter2FromSP)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DeviceId1
END

CLOSE cur 
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Create userdefined Table type and Table to store you expected Result (For instance i have created Temp table)and stored procedure as you required

```
CREATE TABLE ##Result  (
    DeviceId                INT,
    DeviceParameter1FromSP  INT,
    DeviceParameter2FromSP  INT
)

CREATE TYPE DeviceTbl AS TABLE(
    DeviceId                INT,
    DeviceParameter1FromSP  INT,
    DeviceParameter2FromSP  INT
)



IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_DeviceOutPut') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.usp_DeviceOutPut 
END 

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DeviceOutPut]
(
@DeviceTbl AS DeviceTbl READONLY       
)
As 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 From @DeviceTbl)
BEGIN
DECLARE @minid Int,@maxId INT, 
        @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @DeviceParameter1FromSP INT,
        @DeviceParameter2FromSP INT,
        @DeviceId INT

SELECT @minid=MIN(DeviceId) From @DeviceTbl
SELECT @maxId=MAX(DeviceId) From @DeviceTbl

        WHILE (@minid<=@maxId)
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ##Result(
                            DeviceId,
                            DeviceParameter1FromSP,
                            DeviceParameter2FromSP
                            )
                SELECT  DeviceId,
                        DeviceParameter1FromSP ,
                        DeviceParameter2FromSP 
                FROM @DeviceTbl o  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 From ##Result R Where R.DeviceId=o.DeviceId )--Duplicate records cnnot be inserted with this clause
                AND o.DeviceId=@minid
                SET @minid=@minid+1
        END
END


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
         ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;


    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Execute stored procedure  with sample data

```
DECLARE @DeviceTbl AS DeviceTbl

INSERT INTO @DeviceTbl
SELECT 1,100,200 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,120,222

EXEC DBO.usp_DeviceOutPut @DeviceTbl=@DeviceTbl

SELECT * FROM ##Result
```

OutPut

```
Device       DeviceParameter1FromSP   DeviceParameter2FromSP

1             100                      200
2             120                      222
```